# If property exists in object B replace the matching value in object A

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array with a few objects. There are two objects in particular that come back from the API. I have source and highlight keys. Source always returns and if there are fields to highlight then highlight comes back too.

I want to match any properties in highlight and use that and replace the property in source. e.g.

```
document = {
    summary: {
        took: 1,
        count: 230
    },
    results: [
           {
            source: {
                surname: 'Jones',
                forename: 'Tom'
            },
            highlight: {
                surname: ['<em>Jones</em>'],
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

expected outcome:

```
document = {
    summary: {
        took: 1,
        count: 230
    },
    results: [
         {
            source: {
                surname: ['<em>Jones</em>'],
                forename: 'Tom'
            },
            highlight: {
                surname: ['<em>Jones</em>'],
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've seen a few solutions that compare two arrays but not two objects within the same array. Any ideas?

Comment: You wan to replace a string with an array of strings?

Comment: just iterate over the properties of `highlight` and set them in `source`?

Comment: its an array of strings in this example, but just needs to copy whatever is in highlight as long as it has same property name

Comment: results is an array of objects - sorry updated this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this - seems to work ok and only a small amount of logic.

```
res.results.forEach(x => {
  x._source = Object.assign(x._source, x.highlight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind updating the `document` object in-place, you can just loop through `results` and copy over entries from `highlight`:

```
for (const {source, highlight} of document.results) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(highlight)) {
        if (key in source) {
            source[key] = highlight[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// I used `doc` because `document` conflicts with the built-in global
// (I could have used a scoping block)
const doc = {
    summary: {
        took: 1,
        count: 230
    },
    results: [
           {
            source: {
                surname: 'Jones',
                forename: 'Tom'
            },
            highlight: {
                surname: ['<em>Jones</em>'],
            }
        }
    ]
};
for (const {source, highlight} of doc.results) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(highlight)) {
        if (key in source) {
            source[key] = highlight[key];
        }
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I'm guessing these objects won't have any inherited properties, so you could use `for (const key in highlight)` instead of `for (const key of Object.keys(highlight))` and not create the temporary array:

```
for (const {source, highlight} of document.results) {
    for (const key in highlight) {
        if (key in source) {
            source[key] = highlight[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// I used `doc` because `document` conflicts with the built-in global
// (I could have used a scoping block)
const doc = {
    summary: {
        took: 1,
        count: 230
    },
    results: [
           {
            source: {
                surname: 'Jones',
                forename: 'Tom'
            },
            highlight: {
                surname: ['<em>Jones</em>'],
            }
        }
    ]
};
for (const {source, highlight} of doc.results) {
    for (const key in highlight) {
        if (key in source) {
            source[key] = highlight[key];
        }
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Unless I know for sure that it's going to make a performance difference that will matter, I prefer using `Object.keys` so I only get own, not inherited, properties, but I doubt it makes a difference here.